# global filter does not work when click the remove icon

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, primeng, global-filter

I have used priming global filter

```
<input #gb1 type="text" pInputText class="ui-widget ui-text" 
 placeholder="Find"><img class="search" src="assets/images/Search.png" />

 <p-dataTable class="ui-widget-h1-header1" [value]="searchHistoryList" 
[responsive]="true" [rows]="10" [globalFilter]="gb1" #dt1>...
```

Everything is working good. but it's not working if am clear the values when clicking remove icon.

I have checked in https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/filter document. but there also having the same issue with in the latest version :( :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is work around to address your issue.

Trick here is to emit a keyup event when user click on 'X' icon to clear filter text.This is because primeng datatable component only refresh it's filter state when 'keyup' event has occurred.

(search) event is fired when user click 'X' icon, This is when input type='search'. Please correct this in your question statement where you have mentioned as type='text'.

your.component.html

```
<input #gb1 (search)="refreshFilterState()" [(ngModel)]="filterText" type="search" pInputText class="ui-widget ui-text" placeholder="Find"><img class="search" src="assets/images/Search.png"/>


<p-dataTable class="ui-widget-h1-header1" [value]="searchHistoryList" [responsive]="true" [rows]="10" [globalFilter]="gb1" #dt1> --
```

your.component.ts

```
import {InputText} from 'primeng/primeng'
@ViewChild('gb1') inputtext: InputText;

refreshFilterState(){
   this.inputtext['nativeElement'].dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup'));
 }
```

Comment: You can call same function ie clearFilterText() from icon or img element's click event as well. I guess i don't know which remove icon you are referring to? So i added clear button

Comment: @ramesh-rajendran i have modified the answer to work without extra button. but the solution is applicable for input type='search' not for input type='text'. the cross icon does not appear for text.